# Online RSS feed generator with REST API to publish new emails

Tags: email, rss

I want an online service that will manage a feed for me from scratch.
That means

- Create the feed
- Update the feed with some REST API (and email would be awesome!)
- Publish the feed for clients

superfeedr - for example, and I assume pubsubhubbub in general - if I understand this service, is not what I am looking for as it relies on an existing RSS feed.

The problem I want to solve is the massive amounts of emails I am getting at work with Distribution Lists addressed to "World Wide" group for example.

I think it can be awesome if I can send an email to some service that will turn it to a feed and then everyone can register to that feed.

I can't seem to find such a product to install or an online service available.

Answer (score -1):

You can roll your own in [python](https://www.python.org/) with any of [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Klein](https://github.com/twisted/klein) and you will get RSS feeds and an API, which your choice how much to expose.

If you would like to have it externally hosted then AWS, etc., have VMs pre-configured for this sort of operation.

Comment: Thanks, however I am looking for a ready solution without me writing it. Writing it might not be such a simple task if you're looking for something suitable for big organizations.