# A web service to send email newsletters to RSS?

Tags: rss, newsletter

**Example:**

[image]

**Envisioned workflow:**

1. A web service that provides me with an email address to enter into fields such as shown above.
2. Every newsletter sent to this email is automatically converted into an RSS feed item

**Requirements:**

- Should provide a free version

Comment: So you are basically looking for something like the opposite of [rss2email](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rss2email)?

Comment: Definitely related, possibly a duplicate: [Online RSS feed generator with REST API to publish new emails](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/35989/1813)

Comment: Yes, the opposite of rss2email!